# Trying to read data from sensor over serial port and then plot - cannot convert string to float

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to read data from a sensor on COM6. I used Serial.println() in the Arduino module of the embedded chip that hosts the sensor to push the data to the serial port.

When I monitor the serial port, I can see the data being pushed and it is in the range:
-1.00 to 500.00

In my Python script, I open the port, then read from the port but when I try to cast the strings received to float I receive an error that I cannot do it...

Snippets from code :

```
s = serial.Serial(
      port='COM6',
      baudrate=57600,
      parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
      stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
      bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
      timeout=1
)


# Define what we want to graph
x = 0;
while x < 1000:
    a=s.readline()
    a.decode()
    y=float(a)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.ylabel("Pressure")
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    x=x+1
```

error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'--1.80\r\n'
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: `a.decode()` does not work in-place. You need `a = a.decode()`. note that you will get `'--1.80\r\n'` - still not convertible to float, but you can work from there

Comment: you somehow need to parse `'-1.80'` from `'--1.80\r\n'` before you can convert it to float.

Comment: `print(float(b'--1.80\r\n'.strip().replace(b"--", b"-")))` works. The strip removes the `\r\n` part, and you need to replace the `--` with a single `-`

Comment: Given OP statement _When I monitor the serial port, I can see the data being pushed and **it is in the range: -1.00 to 500.00**_, most likely the value is 1.80, not -1.80, i.e. you just **guessing** that `--` needs to be interpreted as _minus_

Comment: Problem is that `--`  is not acceptable for `float`. Please consult documentation why this is, keep special attention to what would be received for values above 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're receiving a binary string and not really a number. You first need to decode it and then manipulate to extract the actual number.

Assuming you receive only negative numbers as `b'--x.xx\r\n'` and positive numbers `b'xxx.xx\r\n'` you can convert them into float as

```
a = a.decode()
if a[0] == '-':
   my_float = float(a[1:].strip())
else:
   my_float = float(a.strip())
```